# Sed print between two matches, and replace with information

Tags: regex, bash, sed, fastq

I want to get an ID from a line across several files, then add some info, before and after this using sed- I don't want to use anything else.
e.g
The original line looks like:

```
19F_4414_2.aln:>tai19F_14 Taiwan19F_14
```

I want to print:

```
pathfind -t lane -id tai19F_14 -f fastq -l .
```

So far I have:

```
grep ">" 19F_4414*.aln | sed -e 's/^.*>/pathfind -t lane -id /1; s/ .*//5'
```

The first substitution works, but the second part doesn't. If I add the asterisk it won't replace the end of the line, but the single full stop only replaces one letter. If you could let me know why, and how to fix this.

Comment: So you need 'pathfind -t lane -id' as static string followed by whatever after :> till space and then static string '-f fastq -l'? Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try it like this

```
sed 's/.*aln:>\(\S*\).*/pathfind -t lane -id \1 -f fastq -l/g'
```

Comment: where "\S" is a metacharacter that will match all digits from the ">" before the space

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
sed 's/>\([^[:blank:]]*\).*$/pathfind -t lane -id \1 -f fastq -l ./' 19F_4414*.aln
pathfind -t lane -id tai19F_14 -f fastq -l .
```

Comment: `sed -n` and `s///p` will suite the request. I guest like you that the *original* line is in fact the result of the grep statment and not the real original line in the file

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
sed -e 's/^.*>/pathfind -t lane -id /1; s/ [^ ]*$/ -f fastq -l ./'
```

Where `[^ ]*$` matches every non-space directly before the end-of-line (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

`sed -r 's/^.*>(.*) .*/pathfind -t lane -id \1 -f fastq -l/` file name.